Question about amplitude of wave
Is it always true that:
$$\text{Incident Amplitude} = \text{Transmitted Amplitude} - \text{Reflected Amplitude}?$$

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754531/sum-of-incident-and-reflected-waves-being-the-transmitted-waves-amplitude

No. It is mostly false. Your equation is only true in the trivial case where reflected amplitude is zero (that is: there isn't a reflection at all), and some very contrived coincidences.
Amplitude is always positive. So if we set transmitted amplitude to zero or any value less than the reflected amplitude, we get a meaningless nonphysical result, as one or the other of incident and reflected amplitude must be negative.
More generally: there is no law of conservation of amplitudes. Energy is conserved, however. If we constrain the medium and the interface to not exchange any energy from the interaction with the wave, then the energy of the incident wave equals the sum of the transmitted and reflected waves. For energies $E$:
$E_i = E_t+E_r$
The energy of a wave is proportional to the square of its amplitude, the square of its frequency, and its wavelength. If it's a wave in a material medium, it's also proportional to the density of that medium.
If we had a circumstance where the medium, the wavelength, and the frequency are all the same for the incident, transmitted, and reflected waves, and if the medium and the interface do not exchange energy from the interaction with the wave, we can write a "conservation of squared amplitude" principle by factoring out all the constants in the above conservation of energy principle and get:
$A_i^2 = A_t^2 + A_r^2$
under that particular circumstance.
